# How to map different request types to different views using the same exact path in Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to have a url something like `api/instrument/{id}` and then based on the request type `GET, POST, DELETE` route the request to a different view in my Django app.

I have these views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http.response import JsonResponse, 
from django.http.request import HttpRequest
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework import status
from Instruments.services import instruments_service
from models import Instrument
from serializers import InstrumentsSerializer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from services import InstrumentsService

# Application views live here
@api_view('GET')
def get_instrument_by_id(request:HttpRequest, id):
    instrument_service = InstrumentsService()
 
    data={}
    try:    
        data = instrument_service.get_instrument_by_id(id)
        return JsonResponse(data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
    except Exception as exc:
        return JsonResponse({"Status":f"Error: {exc}"},status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND , safe=False)


@api_view('POST')
def update_instrument_by_id(request:HttpRequest, id):
    instrument_service = InstrumentsService()
    instrument_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    
 
    data={}
    try:    
        data = instrument_service.update_instrument_by_id(id, instrument_data)
        return JsonResponse(data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
    except Exception as exc:
        return JsonResponse({"Status":f"Error: {exc}"},status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND , safe=False)


@api_view('DELETE')
def delete_instrument_by_id(request:HttpRequest, id):
    instrument_service = InstrumentsService()
 
    data={}
    try:    
        data = instrument_service.delete_instrument_by_id(id)
        return JsonResponse(data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
    except Exception as exc:
        return JsonResponse({"Status":f"Error: {exc}"},status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND , safe=False)
```

I see that people using django make ONE function to hanlde all requests and then they have logioc inside it but that seems so wrong to me. Is there a way to map the same URL endpoint to different function based on the request type?

I see here for example that each url is mapped to a view but the request type is not specified anywhere [URL_Dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: You're using DRF. Viewsets are designed to do exactly what you want: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Comment: @IgorMoraru thanks!! the plain django way seems so clumsy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok based on the class based views that Django REST framework offers and usggested in the comments of the original post I made this class which handles all the request types automatically based on their type at the same endpoint:

```
from uuid import UUID
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.http.request import HttpRequest
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from Instruments.services import InstrumentsService
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from Instruments.services import InstrumentsService
from injector import singleton, inject


# Application views live here
@singleton
class InstrumentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    @inject
    def __init__(self, instrument_service: InstrumentsService, **kwargs):
        self.instrument_service = instrument_service
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def list(self, request: HttpRequest):
        data = {}

        try:
            data = self.instrument_service.get_instruments()
            return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
        except Exception as exc:
            return JsonResponse(
                {"Status": f"Error: {exc}"},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                safe=False,
            )

    def create(self, request):
        instrument_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        data = {}

        try:
            data = self.instrument_service.add_instrument(instrument_data)
            return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, safe=False)
        except Exception as exc:
            return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, safe=False)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk: UUID = None):
        data = {}

        try:
            data = self.instrument_service.get_instrument_by_id(pk)
            return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
        except Exception as exc:
            return JsonResponse(
                {"Status": f"Error: {exc}"},
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                safe=False,
            )

    def update(self, request, pk: UUID = None):
        instrument_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        data = {}

        try:
            data = self.instrument_service.update_instrument_by_id(pk, instrument_data)
            return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
        except Exception as exc:
            return JsonResponse(
                {"Status": f"Error: {exc}"},
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                safe=False,
            )

    def destroy(self, request, pk: UUID = None):
        data = {}
        try:
            data = self.instrument_service.delete_instrument_by_id(pk)
            return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
        except Exception as exc:
            return JsonResponse(
                {"Status": f"Error: {exc}"},
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                safe=False,
            )
```